# How well does ASP.NET Dynamic Data work with Nhibernate today?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, orm, dynamic-data

I know there are a few people working on getting Nhibernate to support ASP.NET Dynamic Data.  Anyone got real life experience of using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current implementation in NHContrib is based on translating the queries to ICriteria.

We faced an issue when you query for a collection members. Say:

```
Get .../Parent(1)/Children
```

In this case you won't get list of Children as you would expect but some list of Parents (as far as I remember).

I think the issue is there because the FROM statement is translated to root criteria. E.g.

```
From parent In Parents Where parent.Id = 1 Select parent.Children
```

... the select part should be now the root of criteria which I think is not ATM.

However a new implementation of Linq2NHib is being developed. Maybe in some time we'd have a propper implementation. At this time - it's no (to be used with Dynamic Data).